# How to Break Force?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I work in unity for some project reflex game and I create the code to move player on button pressed and forward speed keep going. What I need to do to release forward speed only when I press the button, on this moment when I click button forward speed keep going forever.

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if ( moveLeft == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if(moveLeft == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, 0);
        }

        if (moveRight == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        }
        else if (moveRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, 0, 0);

        }

    }

    public void RightMove()
    {
        playerController.transform.position += Vector3.right * 100f * Time.deltaTime;
        moveRight = true;

    }

    public void LeftMove()
    {
        playerController.transform.position += Vector3.left * 100f * Time.deltaTime;
        moveLeft = true;
    }
```

Comment: Have you researched how friction works in the Unity physics engine?

Comment: @Ruzihm im new in this and i don't know soo much i still learnig to be my 80%

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52995190/edit) your question and include the code where you check for `Input`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop when you release the button? Set rb.velocity to Vector3.zero

Comment: Yes i want to stop when i realse the button

Answer (score 0):

In RigidBody  component set linear drag to 1 or any value you want ,And it will slowly reduce speed of your rigid body .